# Differences between std::is_convertible and std::convertible_to (in practice)?

Tags: c++, stl, rvalue-reference, c++20, c++-concepts

According to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) (from what I can gather):

- [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) is a trait class requiring types `From` & `To` to be such that a function with return type `To` that returns a `From` value can compile.
- [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) is a concept requiring types `From` & `To` to be as explained above, **AND** such that an *r-value reference* of type `From` can be converted with `static_cast<To>`.

The requirement imposed by [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) seems relatively straight-forward. Conversely, the *r-value reference* casting requirement of [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) seems oddly specific for such a generic concept that is shown in simple examples for C++20 features.

Being a novice in C++, I could not quite understand some terminology and parts of the supplementary descriptions provided in both webpages and I cannot imagine the exact difference between the requirements of either.

Some inter-related questions:

- What are the practical implications for types `From` & `To` of not only being constrained by [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) but also by the strange r-value reference casting requirement?
- What kind of candidate types for `From` & `To` are *additionally* rejected by the r-value reference casting requirement?
- Why might a programmer want to use either of [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) or [`std::convertible_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to), instead of the other, as constraints for their function return types or parameter types (**aside from just the convenience of concepts**)?

A simpler explanation or an example would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`std::is_convertible<From, To>` (the type trait) checks is type `From` is *implicitly* convertible to type `To`.

`std::convertible_to<From, To>` (the concept) checks that `From` is both *implicitly and explicitly* convertible to `To`. It's rare that this is not the case, such types are ridiculous, but it's nice in generic code to just *not* have to worry about that case.

One example:

```
struct From;
struct To {
    explicit To(From) = delete;
};
struct From {
    operator To();
};

static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<From, To>);
static_assert(not std::convertible_to<From, To>);
```

Comment: Agreed! I'd like to add that it can be important to consider a custom requires clause or concept instead (that, as an example, might make use of _just_ std::Is_convertible instead) when you know the exact requirements you need and can thus allow for more candidate types to be accepted without using a catch-all concept like convertible_to!

Comment: "checks that type `From` is implicitly convertible to type to" is a category error: types aren't convertible to types in C++ - despite that [the library specification says so all over the place](http://wg21.link/lwg3105) - _expressions_ are convertible to types. `is_convertible_v<From, To>` and `is_convertible<From, To>` both actually check that an expression `e` such that `decltype((e))` is `From` is convertible to type `To`.

Comment: +100 for "it's nice in generic code to just not have to worry about that case." - much of the point of the standard library concepts is to make it clear that we consider cases like this pathological by excluding them formally.

Comment: -0.1 for using `not` instead of `!`

Comment: @Casey `add_rvalue_reference_t<From>` :) We don't care about prvalue nonsense other than void... (Edit: actually, we want `remove_cv_t<add_rvalue_reference_t<From>>` - LWG issue submitted)