concept implicitly_convertible_to<From, To>
I need a C++ concept for a type implicitly convertible to another one.
I know about std::convertible_to<From, To> but it includes also explicit conversions (static/const).
My working solution is this:
template<typename From, typename To>
concept implicitly_convertible_to = requires(From &from, void (&func)(To&))
{ func(from); };

Is there already a concept in std:: to achieve my goal? What would it be?

This seems like a yes/no question especially when you have already created/acheived what you wanted?

@user12002570 it is ready answer for anyone has the same question without an answer.

The standard uses "implicitly convertible" as a term, but it has no public trait for that.

What you want is std::is_convertible_v<From, To> which only ensures implicitly convertible.

Realted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644070/differences-between-stdis-convertible-and-stdconvertible-to-in-practice

@康桓瑋 Thank you very much!!! I realize that std::is_convertible_v returns true only for implicit conversions. This is what I want (of course it is not a concept, but I can use it in requires(). Thanks again! It seems that my question is not so yes/no question finally.

If you have the trait, you have the concept: https://godbolt.org/z/1Yh1obPMn
